# Empty synchronized block revisited: data visibility

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686415/in-what-situations-could-an-empty-synchronized-block-achieve-correct-threading-s) stackoverflow topic, which conclusion seems to be that an empty `synchronized` block can always be avoided with a nicer solution. The topic also has some unclear parts to me, which I'll integrate to my below post.

Assume we have a class like this:

```
public class MyThreadClass extends Thread {
  private final OtherComponent mOtherComponent;
  private final Object mLock = new Object();
  private MyHandler mHandler;

  public MyCustomThread(OtherComponent otherComponent) {
      mOtherComponent = otherComponent;      

  public void run() {

      mHandler = new Handler() {...}

      // Other init operations

      mOtherComponent.onMyCustomThreadInitialized();

      // ... other operations (Looper.loop(), actually)
  }

  public void sendMessageWithHandler(int what, int arg) {
       synchronized (mLock) {}
       Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(what);
       msg.arg1 = arg;
       mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
  }

  public void useHandlerInAnotherWay(...) {
       synchronized (mLock) {
            // useful code that needs actual mutual exclusion
       }
       mHandler.sendMessage(...);
  }
}
```

The relevant part of my application works in the following way:

1. The `MyThreadClass` thread is created and started.
2. As an indirect consequence of `mOtherComponent.onMyCustomThreadInitialized()`, another part of my application will start spawning **other threads**. (Note that they aren't started synchronously from this call, that is why I say it's indirect consequence. *The only point is, `mHandler` has been initialized by the time these **other threads** are started*)
3. Each of the **other threads** will call `sendMessageWithHandler(...)` exactly once
4. Yet again other threads (i.e. not the threads mentioned above) call `useHandlerInAnotherWay(...)`, this can happen at any time (after `mOtherComponent.onMyCustomThreadInitialized()`, of course).

My questions:

1. If I'm correct, up-to-date data visibility must be guaranteed when `mHandler` is accessed from other threads than `myThreadClass`, because it is not a `final` field. I don't want to make it `volatile` either, because except for these few `sendMessageWithHandler(..)` calls, `mHandler` is not used from other threads without synchronization (I don't want the `volatile` overhead to be present unnecessarily where it's needless). In other words, when `mHandler` is accessed from those yet other threads via `useHandlerInAnotherWay()`, the `synchronized` there with the "useful code" (i.e. code that actually needs to be a subject of mutual exclusion) also guarantees that the caller thread sees `mHandler` correctly. In `sendMessageWithHandler(..)`, however, the code does not require mutual exclusion, so I decided to put an empty synchronized block to the beginning of `sendMessageWithHandler(...)`. Is this correct? Is there a nicer solution to my problem?
2. The other stackoverflow thread I linked to has the following answer (it's not the accepted one, but was upvoted multiple times):

   > It used to be the case that the specification implied certain memory
   >   barrier operations occurred. However, the spec has now changed and the
   >   original spec was never implemented correctly. It may be used to wait
   >   for another thread to release the lock, but coordinating that the
   >   other thread has already acquired the lock would be tricky.

   Does this mean that the empty `synchronized` does not offer the memory barrier functionality anymore? If I check the Java docs online about `synchronized`, they mention that ALL memory is updated due to it (i.e. thread copies are updated from "main memory" at monitor enter, and "main memory" is updated from thread copies at monitor exit). But they don't mention anything about empty `synchronized` blocks, so this is unclear to me.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html. Maybe a Semaphore or barrier is better for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My software is complex, with parts that aren't listed here, so please let's assume that I need to be general with the functionality I ask about. The component I develop must be more general than what a Semaphore or CycleBarrier would offer.

Comment: If you also mean my statement that "each other thread calls sendMessageWithHandler *exactly once*", then let's disregard "exactly once". It is there just to emphasize that the method is not used often, and thus it wouldn't make sense for the threads to get an own copy of mHandler.

Comment: Some light reading for you: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need any synchronization.

```
(thread 1)          (thread 2)

write
  |
start thread 2
                 \
                    ...
                     |
                    read
```

`read` is guaranteed to see `write`.

---

The semantics of `synchronized` is strictly enforced, even if it's an empty block.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of what happens within the computer, does it mean that *thread 2* **can't have** an outdated copy of mHandler, because it has never accessed it before, right? In other words, if my software guarantees (in some way, e.g. via higher-level constructs) that that the **first read** of a non-final non-volatile variable from another thread is after the **last write** to that variable, am I safe?

Comment: "Higher-level constructs" = e.g. in this case, it means that thread 2 is started after the *last write* to mHandler. Can this be generalized? E.g. what if thread 2 might be started before the *last write* to mHandler, but some constraint in the app guarantees that it will read it only after the *last write*? In this case, I'm also safe I guess. (Of course, robust and maintainable code is also important, I know.)

Comment: It depends on the definition of `after`. The Java memory model defines synchronize-with and happens-before relations that can be considered a formal `before/after` relation. The arrows in my graph conforms to this relation, so the read is `after` write. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, mHandler is not accessed by other threads before its creation, and is not changed during lifetime. As a result, it is safe to read it from other threads without any synchronization. To be absolutely sure, you can read it within synchronized block:

```
public void sendMessageWithHandler(int what, int arg) {
   MyHandler mHandler;
   synchronized (mLock) {
      mHandler=this.mHandler;
   }
   // the rest of code unchanged
}
```

Since "each of the other threads will call `sendMessageWithHandler(...)` exactly once", the overhead would be absolutely negligible. Frankly, your obsession with minimizing usage of synchronization facilities ("I don't want to make it volatile either") looks inadequate in the background of multiple method calls and thread creation. It's worth bothering only when synchronization occurs millions time per second.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point about performance. I just don't like redundant elements (such as volatile + synchronized) in my code, they reduce readability for me.

Comment: ... but increase reliability in case of code changes. They also make to think how to eliminate them safely by minimizing thread interactions and maximizing using local thread memory, which can lead to performance improvement.

Comment: That's the "eternal" question indeed: what to plan and what *not* to plan for the  future ("design for change"). For beginners, your suggestion to put redundant volatiles might be OK, but in this concrete project, I know the nature of potential future changes, and in this concrete case, contaminating the code with unnecessary volatile is not a good solution.