# Java synchronized and happens before

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, happens-before

A synchronized statement establishes a happens-before relation. But im not sure about the details.
In http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html one can read

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock 
>   (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor

I want to know if i understood that correctly. Therefore have a look at the following example.
Lets assume that there are 2 Threads T1,T2 sharing the same instance data of a class Data and object of the class Object.
Now the following code gets executed in the given threads and order:

```
(1)T1:  data.setValue("newValue");
(2)T1:  synchronized(object){}

(3)T2:  synchronized(object){}
(4)T2:  String str=data.getValue();
```

because (1) and (2) are executed in the same thread, one has hb(1,2) and analogue hb(3,4). In (2) is an unlock of the monitor and in (3) a lock of the same monitor, thus hb(2,3), therefore hb(1,4) and str should be equal to "newValue". Is that correct? If not than hb(2,3) should be wrong, but why?

**Edit**

Because details of the class Data is needed to answer the question:

```
public class Data {

private String value

 public void setValue(String newValue){
     value=newValue;
 }

 public String getValue getValue(){
     return value;
 }
}
```

**Edit 2**
its clear, that one cannot guarantee the order of execution. When one has instead

```
(1*)T1:  synchronized(object){data.setValue("newValue");}

(2*)T2:  synchronized(object){String str=data.getValue();}
```

one has also no guarantee that (1*) is exectuted before (2*), but if im right, one has the guarantee that after (2*) one has str= "newValue" if (1*) was executed before (2*). I want to know if the same holds for the 1st example

Comment: This is similar to previous stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686415/in-what-situations-could-an-empty-synchronized-block-achieve-correct-threading-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because (1) and (2) are executed in the same thread, one has hb(1,2) and analogue hb(3,4). In (2) is an unlock of the monitor and in (3) a lock of the same monitor, thus hb(2,3), therefore hb(1,4) and str should be equal to "newValue". Is that correct?

Yes, your logic is correct for this specific scenario. If (and only if) `2` executes before `3` then `hb(2, 3)`. To understand why it should be, imagine a thread process such as the following:

```
localState *= 2;
synchronized(object) {
    sharedState = localState;
}
```

Although `localState` is computed *outside* a synchronized block, it should be necessary for other threads to see this computation to *also* see the correct value for `sharedState`.

However, it's important to understand that there is no reason to expect the order you've asked about as the outcome. For example it could just as easily happen to execute this way:

```
(1)T1:  data.setValue("newValue");

(3)T2:  synchronized(object){}
(4)T2:  String str=data.getValue();

(2)T1:  synchronized(object){}
```

This is bad because now `T1` is writing to a location in memory without synchronization while `T2` is about to read it. (`T2` could even read at the same time the write is occurring!)

---

To understand what happens-before is all about, instead imagine these threads are running concurrently (as threads do) and execute under the following timeline:

```
  |            T1              |              T2
-------------------------------------------------------------
1 | synchronized(object){}     |
2 | data.setValue("newValue"); | String str=data.getValue();
3 |                            | synchronized(object){}
```

Notice how I've aligned these hypothetical actions.

- At point `1`, `T1` acquires the lock and releases it.
- At point `2`, `T1` executes a write while simulaneously `T2` executes a read.
- At point `3`, `T2` acquires the lock and releases it.

But which *actually happens first* at point `2`? `T1`'s write or `T2`'s read?

Synchronization doesn't guarantee the order that threads actually execute with respect to one another. Instead, it is about *memory consistency* between threads.

At point `2`, because there is no synchronization, even if `T1` actually makes the write *before* `T2` reads it, `T2` is free to see the *old* value in memory. Therefore it can *appear* that `T2(2)` happened before `T1(2)`.

Technically what this means is that outside of synchronization, a thread is free to read/write in a CPU cache instead of main memory. Synchronization forces the read/write in main memory.

Now with the second concurrent timeline:

```
             T1              |              T2
------------------------------------------------------------
 synchronized(object){       | synchronized(object){
  data.setValue("newValue"); |  String str=data.getValue();
 }                           | }
```

Although we do not have a guarantee about which thread acquires the lock first, we do have a guarantee that the memory access will be consistent. We also have a guarantee that their actions will not overlap, which was possible in the first timeline.

- If `T1` acquires the lock first, it is guaranteed that `T1`'s synchronized actions will appear as if happening before `T2`'s actions. (`T1` will definitely write before `T2` reads.)
- If `T2` acquires the lock first, it is guaranteed that `T2`'s synchronized actions will appear as if happening before `T1`'s actions. (`T1` will definitely write after `T2` reads.)

Comment: you said "At point 2, because there is no synchronization, even if T1 actually makes the write before T2 reads it, T2 is free to see the old value in memory". That answers my question. Therefore hb(2,3) must be wrong (because hb(1,2) and hb(3,4) will surely hold). Can you explane why? Because in this case i misinterprete:"An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor". Furthermore james large stated the opposite in a comment to the question

Comment: I've edited to clarify.

Comment: There is one thing i still don't understand: in your example timeline T1 acquires the lock first therefore hb(2,3) (with (2) and (3) as in the question). Furthermore no matter how the compiler reoders actions, it holds hb(1,2) because of the program oder (the order i coded it). analogue hb(3,4) and thus hb(1,4). where is the error?

Comment: and maybe your given timeline violates http://jeremymanson.blogspot.de/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html. there you can read that while reordering actions, you cant reoder them arbitrary around synchronized blocks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I changed the order purely as a demonstration. What everybody here is trying to explain is that your original example is unimportant. You should never write code like that because there's no reason to think it will always execute in the timeline you've asked about. It's dangerous because if the threads execute **in any other temporal order** there is no `hb(write, read)`. What's important is the broader context where the single outcome you've asked about is just one of many outcomes and every other outcome is bad.

Comment: junit "test" for confirmation and illustration https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/concurrent-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/jjYBdx4IL/lang/concurrent/OutOfSynchronizedBlockVisibilityTest.java

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not necessary that statement 2 will always execute or happen before statement 3. It can happen that thread 2 will acquire the monitor on object and hence statement 3 will happen before statement 2.

You don't have control over which thread will actually get the monitor of Object and you can't predict.

Comment: Its clear that statement 2 will not ALLWAYS be executed before statement 3, One cant control when one thread get stopped and another thread continues. But WHEN the code is executed in the given order then without synchronization the changes in T1 to data are not visible in T2. i wanted to know if statement 2 and 3 are enough to  make the changes visible (PROVIDED that the code is executed in the given order)

Comment: Yes if you change you data (i.e. object or state of object) in statement block 2 or 3 then it would be visible to other threads when it obtains monitor on Object.

Comment: Thats the point: does one need to do the changes within the synchronize block (2) (which is empty now) or does is suffices to do the changes before the synchronize block as its done now in (1). The way in understand it, it shouldnt matter, because hb(1,2)

Comment: Yes if your object is really critical then it should be within synchronize block.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite that simple. It also depends on what `data.setValue` and `data.getValue` actually do under the covers. Are those methods safe for concurrent (unsynchronized) calls? 
In one contrived example, if data were backed by a `HashMap` and multiple threads call various set methods concurrently, it could [lead to an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695832/explain-the-timing-causing-hashmap-put-to-execute-an-infinite-loop).

In short, you are only able to guarantee the order of execution. You have some limited guarantees to memory visibility between the set and get, but not concurrent calls to set or get having any potential side effects.